# Stop gnome-screensaver from auto-launch with gnome session

Tags: gnome, screensaver, gnome-session

I would like to stop `gnome-session` trying to launch an application each time I login, namely `gnome-screensaver.desktop` (since I have uninstalled in favor of xscreensaver so currently get a syslog error about not being able to find gnome-screensaver, of course because it was removed).

Is there somewhere that lists the applications gnome-session will try to launch that I can edit?

I thought it might be something to do with `~/.config/gnome-session` or maybe `/usr/share/gnome/autostart/`, but I don't see any gnome-screensaver reference....maybe it can be changed with `gsettings`?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, used `sudo find / -iname "gnome-screensaver.desktop"`, which showed me the presence of `gnome-screensaver.desktop` in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`, which was responsible for trying to load the uninstalled gnome-screensaver at each startup. Removing this file removed the error from syslog.

Comment: You can also remove the configuration files by doing `sudo apt-get purge gnome-screensaver`